# What's the difference between undefined and window.undefined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, undefined

If `a` is undefined, this works:

```
if(window.a) {}
```

while this throws an error:

```
if(a)
```

Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`window.a` is a property of `window` and it's *undefined*. `a` is a variable, and it's *undeclared*.

To use a variable, you should first declare it using the `var` statement. Since you didn't declare `a`, the interpreter raises an error. Object properties are not needed to be explicitly declared in order to use them. Crockford writes in *The Good Parts*:

> If you attempt to extract a value from
>   an object, and if the object does not
>   have a member with that name, it
>   returns the undefined value instead.

Comment: However: "window.a = 2; a" -- No 'var' is needed. It just happens that the exception is thrown when an "un-prefixed" identifier look-up runs out of chained scopes to look in. The last context checked is the global context (or 'window'). For most practical purposes, 'var x' in the global context is the same a 'window.x = undefined'. See http://jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html and look at "Identifier Resolution, Execution Contexts and Scope Chains".

Comment: @pst: that's a special case in browsers that all global variables are property of `window`. It's an independent problem of JavaScript. If you run `window.a = 2; a` in Rhino which is a non-browser environment, you still get the reference error.

Comment: @pst: anyway, thanks for your supplement in clarifying the answer.

Comment: örök: Just to clarify further, if you ran `this.a = 2; a` (in the global scope, or standalone function call) though, it would work in any environment. There is still a global object, it's just not always called `window`.